# Custom WFFM Speak Reporting Page

Tags: wffm, reporting, speak

I am trying to display submitted form records on a custom SPEAK reporting page.

I can use the **FormResponsesDataSource** rendering to get the submitted records related to a given form.

Now I need to display them in as a `list/table`.

Is there any default `Rendering` that can be used to display above retrieving `WFFM Form` Response data?

Comment: You can use ListControl component and provide Json data to it. It will show the listing of your records. Check https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/components/listcontrol post for more details

Comment: I am not sure for any default rendering to show as table/datagrid. You can build custom report page using SPEAK UI and javascript framework like knockoutJS/Angular or own custom javascript to make filter etc.